# MST: How to create the main store correctly?

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I want to create rootStore which contains others store. The problem is that the children contain properties like:

`id: types.identifier(types.string),`

And when I create the rootStore, I get an error from the child:

> [mobx-state-tree] Error while converting `{}` to `SomeModelStore`: at path "/id" value `undefined` is not assignable to type: `identifier(string)` (Value is not a string), expected an instance of `identifier(string)` or a snapshot like `identifier(string)` instead.

I tried to use `types.late` but it did not help.

The solution I found is to wrap all properties into `types.maybe`

Examples:

error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/yvnznxyvyj?module=%2Fmodels%2FSomeModelStore.js

workaround:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0mv558yq50?module=%2Fmodels%2FSomeModelStore.js

Answer (score 0):

Here https://codesandbox.io/s/yvnznxyvyj?module=%2Fmodels%2FSomeModelStore.js you create an empty object

```
.model("FirstStore", {
    item: types.optional(SomeModelStore, {})
  })
```

but type

> SomeModelStore

didn't support empty fields. If you write like this

```
export const FirstStore = types
  .model("FirstStore", {
            item: types.optional(SomeModelStore, {
              id: 'defaultId',
              activate: false,
              name: 'defaultName'
            })
          })
```

it will work. Or you can use "types.maybe" instead of "types.optional".

```
export const FirstStore = types
  .model("FirstStore", {item: types.maybe(SomeModelStore)})
```

Also read about [types.reference](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#references-and-identifiers)

I think it's a better way to use it in your case.